# Routing without server-side rendering and basename hardcoded

Tags: reactjs

I use reactjs router in my project, and I noticed that all my URLs are with slash at the end, so refreshing the page redirects to server which I don't have.

Also, redirections are used with paths instead of names, so each time I change my base url, I have to change all redirections and routing initialization.

```
ReactRouter.browserHistory.push('/prefix/newRoute/');

ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.browserHistory},
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/', component: AppController}),
        React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {component: LayoutController},
            React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardController})
        )
    )
, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Is this possible to use hashes instead of slashes in urls? Is this possible to redirect using names?

Comment: If you're using browserHistory then you need a server to redirect non-resource GET requests to your index.html. If you don't have/want that then change to hash-based history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory` and you'll be good to go.

so instead of

```
ReactRouter.browserHistory.push('/prefix/newRoute/');
```

you'll use

```
ReactRouter.hashHistory.push('/prefix/newRoute/');
```

and instead of

```
React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.browserHistory}
```

you'll use

```
React.createElement(ReactRouter.Router, {history: ReactRouter.hashHistory}
```